An Evicted Pod Retains Leadership in AKS
We have a Spring Boot application deployed in an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). It is crucial for us to understand which pod has the leadership role. For this purpose, we use ApplicationListener from org.springframework.context in our Spring Boot application along with Apache Camel and ClusterServiceHelper from org.apache.camel.cluster.
However, we occasionally encounter an issue where the leader pod gets evicted but still retains the leadership role. When the replica set is restored, we end up with n+1 pods where one is evicted but still holds the leadership. This causes inconsistencies and potential downtime in our application.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue? How can we ensure that the evicted pod properly relinquishes its leadership role? Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

This issue where an evicted pod retains its leadership role is a known challenge in distributed systems, especially when using leader election mechanisms like Apache Camel's ClusterServiceHelper. This concept is discussed in distributed systems section in book Designing Data-Intensive Applications.
You can try adding a preStop lifecycle hook your Kubernetes deployment. This hook would call a specific endpoint in your Spring Boot application that triggers the relinquishing of leadership before the pod is evicted.
Assuming that your application uses Apache Camel and Spring's ApplicationListener to manage leadership among pods, add an endpoint let's say-  (/relinquish-leadership) that you can call to manually relinquish leadership
Finally when you deploy the application on aks, update your deployment as below-
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: leadership-app
  labels:
    app: leadership-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: leadership-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: leadership-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: leadership-app
        image: <your-docker-repo>/leadership-app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["sh", "-c", "curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/relinquish-leadership"]


The preStop hook should trigger, calling the /relinquish-leadership endpoint to relinquish the leadership role before the pod is terminated.
